# rake db:migrate Could not connect to server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey I want to see someone example app. So I downloaded it off github and installed the version of ruby they are using ruby 2.0.0 but when I try to do `$ rake db:migrate` I get this error:

```
rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

/home/alain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:796:in `initialize'
/home/alain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:796:in `new'
...(etc)
```

Any idea what I should do ?

**database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: rentmybike_dev
  pool: 5
  username: alain
  password: obama

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: rentmybike_test
  pool: 5

# Add the below...

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: rentmybike_production
  pool: 5
  username: alain
  password: obama
```

Comment: Do you have postgresql installed in your pc ??

Comment: Nope, make that an answer so I can check it

Comment: Thanks, but no need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install postgres you may use these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1 postgresql-server-dev-9.1
```

Then you should set password to newly user

```
sudo passwd postgres
```

You have to ensure that database configuration parameters(like username, password etc) in config/database.yml are correct.
And then:

```
rake db:setup
```

will create databases and restore schemas if any.

Comment: rake db:setup
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "alain"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "alain"

Comment: Could you paste your database.yml file?

Comment: Try to use posgres as username and password you've created early as password. 

Note! This is for development only.